# String Undeclared In C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm sure this is a really simple thing, but I haven't worked in C++ forever.

> 14 C:\Dev-Cpp\mainCurl.cpp `string'
>   undeclared (first use this function)

```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <curl/curl.h>
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> 
> int main(void) {
>       string url("http://www.google.com"); //     
>     system("pause");
> 
>     return 0; }
```

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't declared your namespace.  You need to either declare:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or tell the compiler that "string" is in the standard namespace:

```
std::string url("...");
```

Or you can announce that you are specifically using std::string and only std::string from std by saying:

```
using std::string;
```

Comment: Defining the namespace was the step I missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This a so recurring problem...

You missed `std::` before string, so it will look like `std::string`

That's because `string` belongs to `std` namespace and if you don't use `using` directive you must specify where `string` is.

Alternatively you can use

`using namespace std`; or more conveniently `using std::string` before using string class.

Answer (score 1):

Add `using namespace std;` above the `main()` definition.

Also, you don't need `<stdio.h>` if you include `<iostream>`.  Also, in C++ a function that doesn't take arguments doesn't need a "`void`" argument, simply use parentheses with nothing in between them.

Answer (score 0):

You need `std::string` or `using std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

try `std::string url ("http://www.google.com");`

the string class is in std namespace